# Как присвоить Input'у значение через JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Есть форма с тремя input (ввод, кнопка и вывод) моя цель ввести значение в поле ввода, при нажатии на кнопку отправить данные на обработчик и получившееся вывести в последнем input.

Форма:

```
<form action="../php/handlers/neural.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="input" id="input" placeholder="введите запрос" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="отправить">
            <input name="answer" id="answer" autocomplete="off" value=""></form>
```

далее следует скрипт:

```
        <script>
            $("#btn").bind("click", function(){
                let input = $("#input").val();
                let answer = $("#answer").val();
                
                $.ajax({
                        url: '../php/handlers/neural.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        data: { input, answer },
                        dataType: 'html',
                        beforeSend: function(data){
                            $("#btn").prop("disabled", true);
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#btn").prop("disabled", false);

                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });                 
                });     
                        
            </script>
```

в конце JQ скрпипта есть alert, он корректно выводит обработанные данные ожидаемым методом (окошко в браузере)

Вопрос, как мне эти данные присвоить

```
<input name="answer" id="answer" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

Я новичок в JQ и JS (кЭп)

PS скрипт расположен перед закрывающем тегом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам поможет setter val в [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Вместо

```
  alert(data);
```

Поставить

```
  $("#answer").val(data);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо @aziz-umarov ! Работает!)

Comment: Уважаемый, подскажите. Если я наживаю кнопку курсором, то ajax обробатывает как нужно и выводит результат, но если нажать ENTER то страница перезагружается с посещением обработчика. Как запретить перезагрузку?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Отменяйте событие отправки формы

Comment: А лучше уберите саму форму. Поскольку вы не используете его методы